# Simulating a window-close-button click with a shortcut?

Tags: keyboard, applications, windows, shortcut, bettertouchtool

So I installed RedQuits to enable applications to quit when their last open window closes. However, I never actually use the close button, I only close windows by a shortcut (let's say it's Cmd-W, for example). RedQuits seems to know nothing about this action, and thus applications do not quit when the last window is closed via a shortcut. How can I enable this?

Comment: Why not just use **⌘Q** and quit the app?

Comment: @user3439894 Simply because I'd prefer a single shortcut; I use many workspaces and generally have a whole bunch of terminals (plus maybe finder windows, maybe chrome tabs) open in many of them; it would be preferred not to have to remember if the one I'm desiring to close is the only instance currently open or not

Comment: By default, the keyboard shortcut Command ⌘+W closes the front window.

By default, the keyboard shortcut Command ⌘+Q exits the current program.

For more info, see [Mac keyboard shortcuts](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236).

Comment: This seems like a bug in RedQuits. It should treat the window close button and Cmd-W equivalently.